# Why is this simple code from JavaScript incorrectly variable hoisting?

Tags: javascript, var

I'm trying to understand JavaScript variable hoisting and I'm getting confused with the documentation specified by Mozilla.

The documentation which I am referring to is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_hoisting):

```
console.log(x === undefined); // true
var x = 3;
```

I am using the developer's console on Google Chrome to test this code which is on the latest version. When I execute the above code, I get returned **false** when the Mozilla documentation states that it should be returned **true**.

[image: code example]

This output above means that x is definitely being set to 3 before console.log() is run. Is this documentation specified by Mozilla incorrect or is there something I'm not understanding here?

Comment: The developer console uses `eval`, which has different rules.

Comment: Try to run both lines separately and you'll see `true` after first.

Comment: Did you happen to run it more than once? what do you see for x when you log it? `console.log(x, x === undefined);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return `true` the first time you run it, because `x` starts out as `undefined`. After you run 
`var x = 3`, `x` gets set to `3`, so the next time you run the `console.log(x === undefined)` comparison it returns `false`, as `x` is no longer `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

i run it in Mozilla and chrome and it is true:
for first time the answer is true because it is not defined but will be wrong in next time.
the answer does not change by clearing the console and you must restart browser.